# How to display changes in logins from one week to another segmented by cohorts

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

**Objective:** I must segment Emails by the month of their subscription which will determine the cohorts. In other words, everyone who subscribed in Jan 2018 are in one cohort, feb 2018 in another. Then I need to look at their login activity from one week to another. If 100 subscribers from the Jan2018 cohort log in ISO_WEEK 2 of 2019 and 70 of those log in in ISO_WEEK 3, this is a 70% retention.

**Problem**: I'm not sure how to write my query to have as my first column the cohorts (e.g. Jan2018, Feb2018,Mar2018) and the following columns being the counts of distinct emails' login activity per ISO_WEEK starting in 2019.

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE member
    ([email] varchar(50), [creation_date] Datetime)
INSERT INTO member
VALUES
    ('player123@google.com', '2018-01-01 05:00:00'),
    ('player999@google.com', '2018-01-30 12:00:00'),
    ('player555@google.com', '2018-05-14 20:15:00')
CREATE TABLE login
    ([email] varchar(100), [login_date] Datetime)
INSERT INTO login
VALUES
    ('player123@google.com', '2019-01-07 05:30:00'),
    ('player123@google.com', '2019-01-07 09:30:00'),
    ('player123@google.com', '2019-01-08 08:30:00'),
    ('player123@google.com', '2019-01-15 06:30:00'),
    ('player999@google.com', '2019-01-08 11:30:00'),
    ('player999@google.com', '2019-01-10 07:30:00'),
    ('player555@google.com', '2019-01-08 04:30:00')
```

**What I tried:**

```
;with
cte1 AS (
    SELECT CAST(Creation_Date AS Date) AS Creation_Date
        ,CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,Creation_Date),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,Creation_Date)) AS Cohort
        ,email AS Emails
    FROM member
        ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Logins
        ,yy
        ,login_ISOWeeks
        ,Emails
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST(login_date as Date) AS Logins
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, login_date) AS yy
            ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,login_date) AS login_ISOWeeks
            ,email AS Emails
            ,ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, login_date), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,login_date), email ORDER BY login_date ASC) AS week_count
        FROM login) as f_log
    WHERE f_log.week_count = 1
        )

SELECT cte1.Creation_Date
    ,cte1.Cohort
    ,cte2.yy
    ,cte2.login_ISOWeeks
    ,cte1.Emails
FROM cte1
INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.Emails=cte2.Emails
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Cohort   2019_2  2019_3
jan 2018    2      1
may 2018    1      0
```

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make sense.  Why do members have multiple create dates?  Why is the join on the email address and not on the member id?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of removing this part because it can lead to confusion. This is a defect in the way the db was done. An email can have multiple Ids. That is why im taking the first ID per email, but yes it does not impact my question. Should I remove this part?

Comment: *Should I remove this part?* Yes

Comment: @Simonare and  I just cleared the code, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has lots of weirdnesses.  Why is the `join` key the email address and not the member id?  Why are email members "created" multiple times?

To prevent joins from getting out of hand, I'm summarizing each of the tables before doing the join.  This produces the results you want:

```
select datename(year, m.creation_date) + '-' + datename(month, m.creation_date) as yyyymm,
       count(distinct m.email) as num_members,
       sum(case when l.yyyy = 2019 and l.isoweek = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_201902,
       sum(case when l.yyyy = 2019 and l.isoweek = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_201903
from (select m.email, min(creation_date) as creation_date
      from member m
      group by m.email
     ) m left join
     (select distinct l.email, year(l.login_date) as yyyy, datepart(iso_week, l.login_date) as isoweek
      from login l
     ) l
     on m.email = l.email
group by datename(year, m.creation_date) + '-' + datename(month, m.creation_date) 
order by yyyymm;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac8e978a43b65ff09a221d331e20766a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The issue with the case statement is that its static. I'll have to keep track of the logins for each following ISO_WEEK.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  Editing your existing question would be rude because this would invalidate this answer.

Comment: i wont edit my question but id appreciate it if you could add to your answer unless it is preferable that I repost a new question?